# Checkbox filter in python/django

Tags: python, html, django

I have two div's in my code. Left div has category names and right div has category names, title, and description. Right div values are coming from DB.

I am basically trying to build a checkbox filter functionality in python/django when you click on a category on the left, right div shows the category selected with all the information. By default it shows all the categories and all details.

Here is the code that I have:

**HTML FILE**

```
<div class="category_table">
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input class="reset" type="button" onclick='UnSelectAll(this);' value="Reset" />
    <ul class="vertical menu">         
    {% for category in Categories %}
    {% if 'Sr' in category.label_name %}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id={{category.id}} >
            <span class="label sr">{{category.label_name}}</span>
            <span class="category_name">{{category.name}}</span>
        </li>
        {% elif 'At' in category.label_name %}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="{{category.id}}">
            <span class="label at">{{category.label_name}}</span>
            <span class="category_name">{{category.name}}</span>
        </li>
        {% elif 'Inter' in category.label_name %}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="{{category.id}}">
            <span class="label inter">{{category.label_name}}</span>
            <span class="category_name">{{category.name}}</span>
        </li>
        {% elif 'TRN' in category.label_name %}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="{{category.id}}">
            <span class="label trn">{{category.label_name}}</span>
            <span class="category_name">{{category.name}}</span>
        </li>
        {% elif 'OTP' in category.label_name %}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="{{category.id}}">
            <span class="label otp">{{category.label_name}}</span>
            <span class="category_name">{{category.name}}</span>
        </li>
        {% elif 'FIE' in category.label_name %}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="{{category.id}}">
            <span class="label fie">{{category.label_name}}</span>
            <span class="category_name">{{category.name}}</span>
        </li>
        {% elif 'DEL' in category.label_name %}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="{{category.id}}">
            <span class="label del">{{category.label_name}}</span>
            <span class="category_name">{{category.name}}</span>
        </li>
        {% endif %}                 
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="small-8 cell main-content">
{% for model in Data %}
    <div class="callout medium">
        <p class="entry_name">{{model.name}}</p>
        <p class="entry_info">{{model.sub_name}}<a target="_blank" href=""></a> 
            {% if "At" in model.label_name %}
            <span class="label atm">{{model.label_name}}</span>
            {% elif "Sr" in model.label_name %}
            <span class="label star">{{model.label_name}}</span>
            {% elif "OTP" in model.label_name %}
            <span class="label obs">{{model.label_name}}</span>
            {% elif "DEL" in model.label_name %}
            <span class="label calc">{{model.label_name}}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </p>
        <p class="entry_description">
        {{model.description}}
        </p>
            <div class="text-right">
                {% if "Ats" in model.name %}
                <a class="hollow button" href={{model.about_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link1_name}}</a>
                 <a class="hollow button success hide-for-small-only" href={{model.install_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link2_name}}</a>
                <a class="hollow button secondary" href="javascript:void()" target="_blank">{{model.link3_name}}</a>
                {% elif "CC" in model.name %}
                <a class="hollow button" href={{model.about_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link1_name}}</a>
                <a class="hollow button alert" href={{model.launch_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link3_name}}</a>
                {% elif "Plan" in model.name %}
                <a class="hollow button" href={{model.about_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link1_name}}</a>
                <a class="hollow button alert" href={{model.launch_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link3_name}}</a>
                {% elif "Corr" in model.name %}
                <a class="hollow button" href={{model.about_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link1_name}}</a>
                <a class="hollow button success hide-for-small-only" href= {{model.install_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link2_name}}</a>
                <a class="hollow button alert" href={{model.launch_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link3_name}}</a>
                {% elif "RED" in model.name %}
                <a class="hollow button alert" href={{model.launch_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link3_name}}</a>
                {% elif "Penr" in model.name %}
                <a class="hollow button" href={{model.about_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link1_name}}</a>
                <a class="hollow button success hide-for-small-only" href= {{model.install_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link2_name}}</a>
                <a class="hollow button alert" href={{model.launch_link}} target="_blank">{{model.link3_name}}</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
    </div>              
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**views.py FILE**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from abcd.models import Categories, Data

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    category = Categories.objects.all()
    model= Data.objects.all()
            
    return render(request,'index.html', {'Data':model,'Categories':category})
```

**models.py FILE**

```
from django.db import models

class Categories(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    link1_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True)
    about_link = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    link2_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True)
    install_link = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    link3_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True)
    install_link = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: having difficulty on how to make it work!